# reducing initial startup time for meteor apps

Tags: meteor, startup, jekyll

I'm developing a mobile site where startup time is a critical issue.
Currently meteor apps load the templates for every single page in the whole app, 
[and it seems there are no plans to change this before 1.0](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading) meaning there's an initial startup hit. Overall the experience from then on is really snappy, but i'm trying to optimize the first part - esp. on mobile (asia) 3G networks.

So what techniques are people using to reduce the apparent startup time?

Because of the "full stack" nature of meteor i'm not sure how best to approach this.

For example having a separate bootstrapping/preloader page that loads the meteor app in the background (iframe?), then redirects to meteor URL when ready?

Or combining meteor with static site generated pages and [disabling DDP for the first few](http://meteorhacks.com/building-static-websites-with-meteor.html) pages?

Any techniques appreciated!

Comment: Server-side rendering is on the roadmap: https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering

Answer (score 2):

One quick fix you might look at *for repeat visitors* is Meteor's [appcache package](http://docs.meteor.com/#appcache). With appcache added:

> Once a user has visited a Meteor application for the first time and
>   the application has been cached, on subsequent visits the web page
>   loads faster because the browser can load the application out of the
>   cache without contacting the server first.

According to the specs it is available for most of the major mobile browsers. Of course, it will not help with the initial site visit.

Comment: +1 for appcache. There is also fastrender (3rd party) which can speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by emgee.. fastrender is absolutely worth a look.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been addresses in Meteor 1.5 by using dynamic imports. See [here](https://blog.meteor.com/dynamic-imports-in-meteor-1-5-c6130419c3cd).

Comment: Essentially a link-only answer. Probably more appropriate as a comment.